# Dividing a text file into two files with non-overlapping entries

Tags: python, duplicates, set

Let me explain the problem in detail...

i have two text files (pool files) CL-0.txt and CL-1.txt
I have to divide each of the two into two further parts. CL-0.txt into two further parts xx_0.txt and yy_0.txt and CL-1.txt into parts xx_1.txt and yy_1.txt. the contents of two files are in the following format.
CL-0
    (apple, orange)
    (mango, banana)
    (cake, tea)
    (coffee, sugar)
    (milk, honey)
    (cake, biscuts)
CL-1
    (orange, mango)
    (grapes, coffee)
    (car, icecream)
    (table, chair)
    (window, milk)

to clear what i am refering to as an entry and as an entity:
an entry is:   (apple, orange)
and an entity is:      apple
each entry has two elements. the comma being the separator. 
there should be no duplicate entries or entries.
if an entry or an element has appeared in xx_0.txt, it cannot appear in yy_0.txt and yy_1.txt
if an entry or an element has appeared in yy_0.txt, it cannot appear in xx_0.txt and xx_1.txt
if an entry or an element has appeared in xx_1.txt, it cannot appear in yy_0.txt and yy_1.txt
if an entry or an element has appeared in yy_1.txt, it cannot appear in xx_0.txt and xx_1.txt

each entry is taken one by one and entries are alternately selected for the two files till an entry is written into the file.

the expected output is as follows

the constituent files from CL-0:

*the xx_0 file should have:
(apple, orange)
(cake, tea)
(milk, honey)

*the yy_0 file should have:
(mango, banana)
(coffee, sugar)
(cake, biscuts) cannot be added as cake has already appeared in xx_0

the constinuent files from CL-1:

*the xx_1 file should have: 
(orange, mango)*** a duplicate entry is OK in this case
(car, icecream)

*the yy_1 file would have:
(grape, coffee) *** again a duplicate entry is ok in this case
(table, chair)
(window, milk) cannot be added here as it would have duplicate entity milk which has already appeared in xx_0 file

I attempted half of the problem thinking that if i can successfully divide the CL-0 file into two parts, the rest could be implemented easily with a bit of tweaking.

My effort is as follows:

```
xx_0=open('xx_0.txt','wb') #the file that i want to populate
yy_0=open('yy_0.txt','wb') #the file that i want to populate
file=open('CL-0.txt','r')  # the main file
xx0=set()
xx1=set() # un1 a set against which the desired file has to be checked against for matches
yy0=set()
yy1=set() # un2 a set against which the desired file has to be checked against for matches
for line in file:
    s=line.replace('[,]','')

    s=s.replace('\n','')
    s=s.replace('(','')
    s=s.replace(')','')
    s=s.replace("'",'')

    r=re.split(',',s)
    if L==1:
        for n in r:
            if n not in yy0:
                if n not in yy1:
                    xx0.add(n)
        r1= ', '.join(r)
        xx_0.write(r1)
        xx_0.write('\n')

        L+=1
        continue

    if L==2:
        for n in r:
            if n not in xx_1:
                if n not in yy_1:
                    yy0.add(n)                  
        r2=', '.join(r)
        yy_0.write(r2)
        yy_0.write('\n')
        L=1
```

Comment: what about `(orange, mango)`? what strategy should you employ for discarding?

Comment: You did not initialise your `L`, so I assume it should be `L=1` in the beginning?

Comment: @DJV I wrote the code on the premise that when i start the loop "if n not in yy0" it would give me elements that are not repeating so they would be discarded. Is the presumption wrong?

Comment: @Alfe... yes my bad... L is initialized as 1 :)

Comment: @irfanbukhari Try to state your problem and your target better. I see you've commented a lot on the answer below, but you should also consider editing your question. Adding a bigger example of input and the expected output is also a plus.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the lines shall be put alternating into two different files:

```
inputFile = file('CL-0.txt')
out = [ file(fileName, 'wb') for fileName in [ 'xx_0.txt', 'yy_0.txt' ] ]
done = set()
for line in inputFile:
  elements = re.match(r'\s*\(\s*([^,])*\s*,\s*([^)])*\)\s*', line)
  if elements in done:
      continue
  out[0].write(', '.join(elements) + '\n')
  done.add(elements)
  out = out[1:] + [ out[0] ]  # round robin
for f in out:
  f.close()
```

But I did not understand what the purpose of these `xx1` and `yy1` sets was.  Your code definitely wasn't explaining it (it did not write to these at all) and your text wasn't helpful enough either.  Maybe you want to elaborate on that?

Comment: In addition to comparing the files against each other for matches. Each of the two files have to be compared against xx_1 and yy_1. These sets would be populated using the same technique but from a different file.
set xx_0 has to be compared against elements in yy_0 and yy_1
and set yy_0 has to be compared against elements in xx_0 and xx1

Comment: Let me elaborate it a bit more...
From a File CL-0 i have to populate two files
each having non-overlapping entires (the pairs should not be matches nor should each element of each pair be repeated in the two files)
the xx_0 set has to be checked against the sets yy_0 and yy_1
and the yy_0 set has to be checked against the sets xx_0 and xx_1

Comment: Let me elaborate it a bit more...
From a File CL-0 i have to populate two files
each having non-overlapping entires (the pairs should not be matches nor should each element of each pair be repeated in the two files)
If the pair is repeated, it should be discarded. If any element in a pair is repeated, the whole pair should be discarded.
the xx_0 set has to be checked against the sets yy_0 and yy_1
and the yy_0 set has to be checked against the sets xx_0 and xx_1. 
@Alfe... your help does well for the exact "pair" matches. But I need help with getting rid of re-occurring elements in a pair.

Comment: each pair has two elements... (orange, mango)
what i need help with is that if orange has already occurred in an entry and if it occurrs again with a different entry in a different pair, it should be discarded even if the other element in the pair has not been repeated. e.g if (orange, mango) has occurred in a file then (orange, peach) should be DISCARDED. please need help

Comment: I still find your explanations hard to understand, so maybe I'm misled.  Anyway, I propose to have another set then for the single elements.  Would that be feasible?